# ActiveRecord queries breaking with nulls first ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model, `topic`, that includes this:

```
has_many :messages, -> { order('source_answer_id asc nulls first').order(id: :asc) }
```

Elsewhere, when trying to call this relation, it breaks with certain parameters. For example, the following results in an error.

```
topic.messages.last.id
```

Results in

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
LINE 1: ..." = $1  ORDER BY source_answer_id asc nulls first DESC, "mes...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "message".* FROM "message" WHERE "message"."topic_id" = $1  ORDER BY source_answer_id asc nulls first DESC, "message"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

I assume this is because the `nulls first` obfuscates the `asc`.

How can I get ActivieRecord to play nice with `nulls first`?

Answer (score 0):

DESC and ASC means for the nulls nothing. they are coming before or after the non-null values:

> The NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST options can be used to determine whether nulls appear before or after non-null values in the sort ordering. By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null value; that is, NULLS FIRST is the default for DESC order, and NULLS LAST otherwise.

for this `order by` first sorted source_answer_id  ascending with nulls comes first and message.id sorted descending with nulls comes last

```
ORDER BY source_answer_id ASC NULLS FIRST,"message"."id" DESC NULLS LAST limit 1
```